# SYMFONY2 Sluggable minimal configuration

Tags: php, symfony, slug

I installed **StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle** identical with that [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html).
In contrast, page renders very slowly, because about 5 minutes. I you need only  **sluggable** funcionality in the user entity (FOSUSERBUNDLE). I think it schould work faster without some elements.

What is the minimum configuration to run only sluggable with this package. Are all mappings are needed (watch [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html))?

I need **config.yml** example.

**EDIT**
After adding listener my config.yml looks:

```
    ...
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:  ~
                    gedmo_translatable:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                        is_bundle: false
                    gedmo_translator:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoTranslator # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                        is_bundle: false
                    gedmo_loggable:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoLoggable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mappingmapping
                        is_bundle: false
                    gedmo_tree:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoTree # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                        is_bundle: false

...
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    class:
        sluggable:      ~
...
```

My Entity with slugg:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Profile
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProfileRepository")
 */
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;
     /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title", "name"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="voivodeship", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $voivodeship;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;


     /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $user;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     *
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set voivodeship
     *
     * @param string $voivodeship
     *
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setVoivodeship($voivodeship)
    {
        $this->voivodeship = $voivodeship;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get voivodeship
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVoivodeship()
    {
        return $this->voivodeship;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param string $category
     *
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
     /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string
     */
     public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }
}
```

Now site did not generate. Refreshed database and nothing helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified listener definition from Alsatian's answer and it's working now.

```
# app/config/config.yml
stof_doctrine_extensions:
default_locale: en
orm:
    default:
        tree: false
        timestampable: false
        sluggable: true
        translatable: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to activate the sluggable listener :

```
    # app/config/config.yml
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    class:
        sluggable:      ~
```

And create your slug property :

```
<?php
namespace Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entity
{
    ...

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"username"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    ...
}
```

Comment: After adding listener nothing changed. I completed the question of my files

Comment: You only need what I wrote. Please remove every listener in mappings ...

Comment: And don't forget to remove all not wanted SQL tables that was created with your wrong configuration (normaly 4).